# What is the diffrence between SPMD and SIMD?

Tags: terminology, parallel-processing, simd

I just cant understand whats the diffrence between them...

is SPMD is in the programming level and SIMD in the hardware level ?

example would be good !

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SIMD is vectorization at the instruction level - each CPU instruction processes multiple data elements.

SPMD is a much higher level abstraction where processes or programs are split across multiple processors and operate on different subsets of the data.

Comment: So if SIMD is about instruction on ONE cpu that can process multiple data  - where is the parallelism here? is it the ability to manipulate multiple data ?

Comment: @RanZilber: yes, with SIMD in one instruction you process N data points instead of 1, where N is typically 4, 8 or 16 for typical SIMD implementations on common CPUs. So you get N-way data parallelism at the instruction level.

Comment: @PaulR Maybe, it's clearer if you add a precision. With SPMD, you have a single program which takes the thread ID as an argument. This ID can be used in a switch case statement for example.